# Get build information from jenkins using rest api

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-api

I want to retrieve the build summary for last 3 days from Jenkins using its rest API's and save the result as an XML file, How I can proceed with this?

Comment: Go to `/api/` on your Jenkins instance.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for the inputs :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could read full guide in:

```
http://YOUR_JENKINS:8080/job/YOUR_JOB/api/
```

The build sumary in XML format:

```
http://YOUR_JENKINS:8080/job/YOUR_JOB/api/xml
```

Retrieve the name of the first 10 builds

```
http://YOUR_JENKINS:8080/job/YOUR_JOB/api/xml?%20tree=jobs[name]{0,10}
```

Comment: I couldn't get the last one to work, it just timed out

Comment: @jcollum not sure. I've tried the last one again and it works well.